# Embedded WebBrowser control intercepts horizontal scroll events

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-phone-8

We've got a `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser` embedded control inside a `StackPanel`, inside a `PivotItem` on Windows Phone 8. In a simplified form, it's basically:

```xml
<Grid>
  <controls:Pivot Width="425" Margin="50,0,0,0">
    <controls:PivotItem Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="400">
      <StackPanel>
        <!-- Other stuff -->
        <phone:WebBrowser Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" Width="400" Height="600" />
      </StackPanel>
    </controls:PivotItem>
  </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

The problem is, unlike other controls, the `WebBrowser` seems to intercept all scroll events, even if no internal scrolling is required. This basically means that, once the `WebBrowser` control is on the screen, the only way to scroll to the next `PivotItem` is to tap on the headers at the top, which is a drag.

Some tricks I've tried include

- Forcing the internal `ScrollViewer`'s `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled`
- Manually capturing `ManipulationDelta` and/or `ManipulationCompleted` events and propagating them up myself — they don't fire as you would expect them to
- Trying every possible permutation of the `WebBrowser` and parent's width to make it realize that no scrolling is necessary.

It seems like something out of the ordinary is going on here. Any suggestions on how to change this behaviour?

Comment: You can add kind of List (LongListSelector for example) instead of WebBrowser and get the same issue. I suppose something wrong with the two scrolls appears one inside another. Also if you'll place the webbrowser directly to the root of pivotitem (without stackpanel) it appears to be fine.

Comment: @Adrian Petrescu Did you solve the issue you mentioned? if so, How did you solve?

Answer (score 2):

Tryout this link. I think Mr.Colin Eberhardt's solution will help you to solve your issue,
http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/

Comment: This solution is still not passing the swipe gesture from webbrowser to pivot. It just controls the horizontal scroll. thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution here http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone%E4%B8%ADPivot%E5%86%85%E5%B5%8CWebBrowser%E6%97%B6%E7%9A%84%E6%A8%AA%E5%90%91%E6%BB%91%E5%8A%A8%E5%A4%84%E7%90%86. Download the source code and go through the code. But the app should be Pivot app instead of Panorama app.